# ImageMagick PDF delegate failed, GhostScript missing

Tags: c#, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I'd like to use ImageMagick to convert PDF in PNG. I found out that I need GhostScript installed on the computer to make ImageMagick work properly.

This software I'd like to develop should be used by other people too. I can't ask them to install GS too on their computer, so I was wondering if there's a way to add references of Ghostscript to my project so I don't need people to install other software other than mine.

Can it be done? Is there a way to use GhostScript and ImageMagick without installing anything on the computer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you can use software without it being installed on the computer, unless you plan to provide a cloud service providing them over the internet.

I also don't see why you can't expect people to install other software,its pretty common practice.

NB you don't require ImageMagick to render PDF to PNG, Ghostscript does that quite happily (indeed that's why ImageMagick needs it). Of course you might well want to use IM to further process the resulting PNG.

You can, of course, build GS into your own application, but remember that GS is licenced under the AGPL so your application will need to be AGPL compatible as well, or you will need a commercial licence. Building GS into your application won't make it available for use by ImageMagick though.

Comment: And is there a guide on how I can buid GS on my application?

Comment: There is quite a lot of documentation in the sources, have you looked ?